# Can I create a new map on the fly and pass as a function parameter?

Tags: c++

In C#, I could so something like the following:

```
        public static Dictionary<string,string> ExampleFunction(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
        {
            return dict;
        }

        public static void CallingFunction()
        {
            ExampleFunction(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "test", "test" } });
        }
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in C++? Forgive me if this is answered elsewhere--this seems like a basic question, but I must not be using the right search terms. This comes closest to what I was looking for but no cigar: [Creating a new object and passing in method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972855/creating-a-new-object-and-passing-in-method-parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> ExampleFunction(
    const std::map<std::string, std::string>& dict) {
  return dict;
}

void CallingFunction() {
  ExampleFunction({ { "test", "test" } });
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Q5yAn_)

Comment: That's great, thanks! Can I do something similar when doing a map<string, map<string,string> >? I've tried map<string,map<string, string> > test = {"Test", { { "test", "test" } } }; and get a compiler error that says no matching constructor

Comment: You are a pair of braces short. `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > test = { {"Test", { { "test", "test" } } } };`

Comment: Ah, figures....thanks again for your help. Much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename B> struct Dictionary
{
    A Var1;
    B Var2;
};

template<typename A, typename B> Dictionary<A, B> func(Dictionary<A, B> dict)
{
    return dict;
}

int main()
{
    auto res = func(Dictionary<int, int>{123, 445});
    printf("%d - %d\n", res.Var1, res.Var2);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Map was more what I had in mind, but this is cool to see Dictionary actually implemented this way!